# help with an add script

Tags: php

I looking to sum three values of the price field if selected.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM shoes
    WHERE tray on tray.product_id = shoes.id";
 $sth = mysql_query($sql);
 $variety = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
echo'<div>
<p>'. $variety['name']. '</p>
<p class="price">'. $variety['price']. '</p>
<input name="price" type="checkbox" value=""  />
</div>
<div>
<p>'. $variety['name']. '</p>
<p class="price">'. $variety['price']. '</p>
<input name="price" type="checkbox" value=""  />
</div>
<div>
<p>'. $variety['name']. '</p>
<p class="price">'. $variety['price']. '</p>
<input name="price" type="checkbox" value=""  />
</div>
}
```

if you notice each iteration will have a checkbox input and users can choose one or the three if they one. Now how can I sum how if user chooses more than one price?

Comment: If you want this to be dynamic, you are looking at JavaScript that intercepts changes to the check boxes

Comment: yes that would be a nice idea to have an dynamic script that everytime I check the check boxes it automatically updates the total.

http://www.nyhungry.com/example2.php?subject=4&id=2&register=&menu=38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, you want PHP to treat your input as an array, so change your HTML like so-> add [] after the name.

```
<input name="price[]" type="checkbox" value=""  />
```

Then in PHP just access the form variable name like you normally would and loop through the values and sum them.

Answer (score 1):

Add brackets after each of the price names to tell PHP that price should be an array:

```
<input name="price[]" type="checkbox" value=""  />
```

Then in PHP you will get the variable $price (which will be an array) and sum all of its values (it will only contain the checked values). Something like:

```
<?php
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $total = 0;

  foreach( $price as $p )
  {
     $total += $p;
  }
?>
```

Comment: a more efficient way would be to use array_sum()

Comment: Will I need to declare $price=array; at the beggining?

Comment: @jona No, $_POST['price'] is giving $price an array.

Comment: @Ben Yes, but since he is a beginner it cant hurt to learn how to iterate through an array.

Comment: There is an argument which is failing and it's probably the definition of price which fails at the foreach. The code below is a representatino of what I have don't know what's could be wrong int he set up.

foreach($product['varieties'] as $variety){ 
<p>' . $variety['price']. '</p>
<p class="price">' . $variety['price']. '</p>
$price = $variety['price'];
  $total = 0;

  foreach( $price as $p )
  {
     $total += $p;
  }
echo $total;
}

Error is as: 

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home3/stores/public_html/example2.php on line 303
0

Comment: Your $price = $variety['price']; is wrong. It should be just he way I have it in my example... naming all checkboxes price[] will create an array.

Comment: ok 
what about this code

<?php
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $total = 0;

  foreach( $price as $p )
  {
     $total += $p;
  }
?>


do you use it in the page where the form action send the user?

Comment: action="cart.php"? in cart.php?

Comment: the code looks right... you put that code in cart.php..... You really should read the PHP Tutorial at w3 school http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp